# Parse AJAX HTML response and fetch object Nodelist and display as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-parsing, nodelist

I am making some AJAX call in plain javascript that returns me a HTML.
In callback I can see response in HTML. I can parse response that contains [Object Nodelist]. Now in my HTML there is select list and I want to replace this select list with this updated Nodelist I received in ajax response. But the problem is it is nodelist and I want it to appear as . so that I can replace my original select list with ajax response.

MY CODE:

```
function loadFacility(callback)
{
    //alert('In loadFacility');
    var xmlhttp;
    var keys=document.firstCallInformation.facilityselect.value;
    var urls="http://localhost:8080/webfdms/showFirstCallInformation.do?vitalsId=366";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
             //var some=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
            console.log(response)
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
function loadFacilityCallback(response){
    if(response != null){
        //alert(response);
        console.log(response);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = response;
        document.getElementById("facilityselect").innerHTML = div.querySelector("select#facilityselect");
    }
}
```

Now here in the **callback function(loadFacilityCallback)** I am creating DIV element and parsing the response. But when I assign updated select list using `div.querySelector("select#facilityselect")` to the `document.getElementById("facilityselect").innerHTML` I can not see anything in my select list since it is [Object Nodelist]. Now how can I get my option values from nodelist.

Please help.

Comment: try .item() Which Returns the node at the specified index in a node list

Comment: .item() on which line ?